# align text at same horizontal align as image

Tags: html, css

I want to make a logo which looks like this:

[image: Logo]

but I can't get it to work, this is what I have at the moment:

[image: Current Logo]

I want the logo on the left to be the same as the first picture I uploaded, does anyone know how to do this?

I tried with `vertical-align: middle` which doesn't work, and I tried `display: flex` and then `align: center` but that doesn't work either.

Here is my attempt:

```css
header {
  padding-top: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  background: #1b1b2e;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
}

header img {}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="Logo"> <img src="img/logo_shape.png" alt="Logo">
    <h1>Dublin apps</h1>
    <h3>Ipad applications</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="nav"> 
    <a href="#">Home</a> <a href="#">Ipad Apps</a> 
    <a href="#">Demonstrations</a> 
    <a href="#">Leogards Media</a>
    <a href="#">connect us</a> 
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: also the i in the logo doesnt matter

Comment: please share the code that you have attempted to achieve this.

Comment: Would appreciate if you share some code you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: Your CSS targets `#logo` but your `id` says "Logo". Change the L to lowercase, and your `display: flex` will start working.

Comment: @Morris please send answer as an answer, not as a comment

Comment: thanks, would have never seen that it is fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer.

```css
header {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #1b1b2e;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

header img {
  width: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

#nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #111;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.logo-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.logo-text h1, .logo-text h3 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo-text h1 {
  font-size:16px;
}

.logo-text h3 {
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/o_collection_png/green_dark_grey/512x512/plain/leaf.png" alt="Logo">
    <div class="logo-text">
      <h1>Dublin apps</h1>
      <h3>Ipad applications</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav"> 
    <a href="#">Home</a> <a href="#">Ipad Apps</a> 
    <a href="#" class="active">Demonstrations</a> 
    <a href="#">Leogards Media</a>
    <a href="#">connect us</a> 
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned Rickard Elimää your CSS targets #logo but your id says "Logo".

We must also put

```
flex-direction: column;
```

and some other adjustment to make it work.

I also created the graphic element in the css logo as it is very simple, if you want an image instead of the pseudo element you can put it inside **h1** like this:

```
<h1><img src="path_to.png" alt="i">Dublin apps</h1>
```

and remove the css rules for the pseudo element.

```
#Logo h1:before
```

You will need to change the logo font to match the one in the image

```css
header {
      padding-top: 24px;
      padding-bottom: 24px;
      background: #1b1b2e;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      align-items: center;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    }

    header a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      color: white;
    }


    #nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    #Logo {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      color: white;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

#Logo h1, #Logo h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

#Logo h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#Logo h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#Logo h1:before {
  content: "i";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCDE.png" alt="">
<header>
      <div id="Logo">
        <h1>Dublin apps</h1>
        <h3>Ipad applications</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="nav"> 
        <a href="#">Home</a> <a href="#">Ipad Apps</a> 
        <a href="#">Demonstrations</a> 
        <a href="#">Leogards Media</a>
        <a href="#">connect us</a> 
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQwDB.png)Use this css

```
#logo img{
     margin:0 auto;
     display:table;
```

}

Comment: can you please explain to me what display:table does? my teacher said to me i could better avoid using display table and position absolute

Comment: @Morris                                #Logo {
    display: table;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}